# On a Mac, I created a .html document locally but in a browser I just see HTML source

Tags: html, macos, browser

**On a Mac**, I created a file with some very simple html, e.g. `<h1>my web page</h1>`  I save it as .html.  I start firefox or Opera and I use open file, but I just see the content as html source, e.g. I see `<b>` tags, etc.

If you want all the code here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Web Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: 'Rich text' format was the issue.  See my answer below.

Comment: make sure its not called `*.html.txt`, and paste your code into the question.

Comment: What editor did you use? Do you have some sort of rich text formatting turned on?

Comment: I added all the code.  The file is called mywebpage.html  It has just a html extension.  Mac shows it as a html doc in finder.  This is not on windows.

Comment: I've opened it in firefox and opera, same effect.

Comment: file:///Users/durrantm/lots_of_dirs/play_wth_j2.html

Comment: If I create it with an IDE, e.g. rubyMine, same filename, same extension, same 'kind' it works. Can't see what the difference is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Shad was actually on to the right answer here.**

The problem was that I was using the standard mac text editor - `textedit` - and it was saving the document type as rich text formatting (the standard).  I had to go into textedit preferences and make change the default formatting for a new document from Rich text to Plain text.  This fixed the problem! 
As this was a stupid problem, yet not obvious to most I'll post the screen shot of where you change that default new document preference in textedit prefs.

[image]

Comment: It works, need only to add that these settings won’t take effect on the current work. New html file must be created.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of some silly header stuff. Browsers use the header information to decide how to render it, not the extension, I think. You know, there's a tiny chance that any file- exe, jpg, png, txt- could actually appear as valid HTML because they're both just files at heart.

Comment: Totally makes sense.  I can change the extension but that isn't this.  How do I actually change the header information ?

Answer (score -1):

Open the "Get Info" of the file by right clicking on the file (or control click) and selecting Get Info. Under the section titled Name & Extension un-check Hide extension. You will see that mac has added an extension (usually .txt), just remove that extension and close

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did this and it didn't help.  i tried .html .htm and no extension and I check each one with finder properties, none are working.

Comment: -1 because I did not see the .txt so this was not a fix (though I appreciate the help as always).